# Syntax error - unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python, neural-network, lstm

Unexpected EOF while parsing. I can't figure it out.

```
outputs = []
for i in range (batch_size):

batch_state = np.zeros([1, hidden_layer], dtype=np.float32)
batch_output = np.zeros([1, hidden_layer], dtype=np.float32)

for ii in range (window_size):

    batch_state, batch_output = LSTM_cell(tf.reshape(inputs[i] 
        [ii], (-1, 1)), batch_state, batch_output)

  outputs.append(tf.matmul(batch_output, weights_output + bias_output_layer)
```

Comment: Make sure the intentions are correct. I think the first `for` should not be indented.

Comment: The error is because of the unmatched parentheses.

Comment: Any decent IDE should help you avoid problems like these.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar you are right.

Answer (score 0):

If you fix the indentions (only indent after a `for:` not before, always use the same indention (4 spaces)), remove the linebreak in line 10/11 and add another closing parentheses to the last line, the code runs without a parsing or synstax error:

```py
outputs = []
for i in range (batch_size):

    batch_state = np.zeros([1, hidden_layer], dtype=np.float32)
    batch_output = np.zeros([1, hidden_layer], dtype=np.float32)

    for ii in range (window_size):

        batch_state, batch_output = LSTM_cell(tf.reshape(inputs[i][ii], (-1, 1)), batch_state, batch_output)
        outputs.append(tf.matmul(batch_output, weights_output + bias_output_layer))
```

Of course it still doesn't work as it uses variables that are not defined in the code snipped.